# Zip file has different size after copied to flash drive

Tags: command-line, zip, storage

I created a zip archive named `tmp.zip`.

It has a size

```
$ du -h tmp.zip
1.7G    tmp.zip
```

I copied it to flash drive

```
$ du -h /media/tb/tmp.zip 
1.5G    /media/tb/tmp.zip
```

What's wrong here? How can I check what is missing in the archive on
the flash drive if something is missing?

Comment: `du`'s not the best for checking if files are the same. Compute a checksum (md5sum or similar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two filesystems most probably use different blocksize, this can change the graininess with which filesizes can be assigned.

Comment: That is a *very* different block size to make one file ~200MB different. (I'm tempted to say impossibly different.) I suggest you add using `stat` or `ls -s` to confirm the logical size is the same.

Comment: @derobert I copied it to SD card, the size was 1.7G and md5sum as Mat suggested was the same. I will try it with flash drive as well later.

Comment: What filesystem did you use on flash disk?Did you try to extract 1.5 G zip file? any errors or ok ?1MB = 1000 KB or 1MB = 1024KB Did it cause a size different?